# Can't get a response from API using okhttp library

Tags: java, android, response, okhttp

I'm having issues with getting a response from the MindeeAPI when sending a image to the server. First I have a camera intent which takes the image and then I convert it into a file, but I can't seem to get the JSON response neither in the `logcat` nor in a `textView`, what could be the problem?

Here's the API class code:

```
public class MindeeApiManager {

public static void callMindeeAPI(File imageFile, String apiKey, Callback callback) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    // Request Body
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("document", "image.jpg", RequestBody.create(imageFile, MediaType.parse("image/jpeg")))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.mindee.net/v1/products/mindee/expense_receipts/v5/predict")
            .header("Authorization", "Token " + apiKey)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    // Execute the API call
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
}
```

Code from MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data");
        assert imageBitmap != null;

        //Convert bitmap to file
        File imageFile = convertBitmapToFile(imageBitmap);

        //API class call
        MindeeApiManager.callMindeeAPI(imageFile, apiKey, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("MindeeAPI", "API call failed: " + e.getMessage());
                txtItems.setText(e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseBody = response.body().string();

                txtItems.setText(responseBody);
                Log.d("MindeeAPI", "Response Code: " + response.code());
                Log.d("MindeeAPI", "Response Body: " + responseBody);
            }
        });
    }
}

private File convertBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imageFile = null;
    try {
        //Creates a file in the cache directory
        File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
        imageFile = new File(cacheDir, "temp_image.jpg");

        //Compresses the bitmap and writes it to the file
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageFile;
}
```

Comment: The first step would be not to ignore all non RESULT_OK result situations and print all the data you get to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Checked if the image bitmap is saved to data and it is. Tried to send the image as a base64 string and seeing if the request is sent, but the api request doesnt show in the logcat either.